# emacs tab and spaces indentation for visual studio projects

Tags: emacs, tabs, indentation, spaces

At my work i have switched to using emacs from Visual Studio. Since codebase is large and my other team mates use Visual Studio (VS), i can not remove the tabs.

For myself i did this :

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
;; tab-width
(setq-default tab-width 1)
```

So everything looks good to me, but when i am putting code for review, it looks unintended for them or in other editors.

changing `tab-width` to 4 made things better but i have to remember to do `C-q <TAB>` again and again.

I start facing the problem :

The code has lines of average of length 130. Some go as far as 200. And i work on multiple buffers like 4 at a time. This makes code hard to read.

I then let the emacs default take charge and remove both `indent-tabs-mode nil` and `tab-width` line and i found that it was much better. It was automatically inserting tab and everything for me.

However, i had little bad experience at some places which are looking good in VS.

Also i had put these configurations from `default-basics github repo`. Contrastingly, there is another article on `spaces are evil`. Internet is full of one or another and i am confused.

What is the general guidelines that i can follow ?

SO i see Tab as 1 space it would be great. But in file they should go as "they should be".

Comment: What exactly do you want the indentation to look like?

Comment: Is there a generic config that would adjust according to project ? And i want to see tabs in 1 space for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of

```
tab-width 

Documentation:
Distance between tab stops (for display of tab characters), in columns.
This should be an integer greater than zero.
```

and

indent-tabs-mode

Documentation:
   Indentation can insert tabs if this is non-nil.

I **removed** the `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`
and set the `(set tab-width 1)`

so now emacs handles the indentation and i see the tabs as 1 column width.